# How its set with grid-template-columns: [outer-start] 1fr [center-start] 1fr [center-end] 1fr [outer-end]?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, subgrid

I have this code from a code snippet for CSS grid and found it really confusing.

`grid-template-columns: [outer-start] 1fr [center-start] 1fr [center-end] 1fr [outer-end];`

My doubt is, here will there be 3 columns or 4 columns?

Comment: there are 3 columns (this *names* the grid lines) - see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#named-lines

Comment: Then why 4 column names are given as: outer-start, center-start, center-end, outer-end ?

Comment: they are not column names, they are *grid line* names... if there are 3 columns then there are 4 grid lines

Answer (score 0):

There will be 3 columns and 4 column-grid-lines. In terms of explicit column numbers and sizing

```
grid-template-columns: [outer-start] 1fr [center-start] 1fr [center-end] 1fr [outer-end];
```

is equivalent to

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

The thigs inside `[` and `]` are [gird line names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid_Lines). I suggest you to read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines) for an exhaustive explanation. These grid line names then later can be used to position grid-items, e.g.

```
.grid-item1 {
  grid-column-start: center-start;
  grid-column-end: outer-end;
}
```